# Access Modifier of Methods in Enterprise JavaBean

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, ejb, ejb-3.0

What is the good practice of defining methods in EJB? I have EJB which extends an Abstract Class.

Is it a good practice to define protected methods in that Abstract Super Class and access it from Child EJB?

Answer (score 1):

Well EJB3 (at least 3 and 3.1, I believe EJB 3.2 comes with some changes here) obliges to provide interfaces for the behavior of the EJB class. So, the important methods of the EJB need to be public.

As a OOP principle, it is best to use the most restrictive access modifier possible; so if possible use private. Also instead of inheritance, try to reuse code with composition.

Comment: Could you please explain "instead of inheritance, try to reuse code with composition."?

Comment: @TapasBose One starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance . Also see the beginning of Design Patterns classical book by Gang of Four.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Java beans are useful components to build your logic a part from your client and respect the notion of the OOP of hiding the implementation.
Whenever you want to create a EJB, also a simple one, you have to define which methods you want to expose, depending on the use that you will do of your logic.

In order to expose the "service" to your client you will define which methods can be called and this is done through defining an interface that is a remote interface. For a more general comprehension you can look a the concept of Session façade [j2ee patterns](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/SessionFacade.htm).

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface IUser {
public Boolean doLogin(String user, String pass);
public void doLogout();
}
```

Inside your interfaces you should be able to provide all the operation, or a set of operation, that will be used by the client using your EJB(stateless/statefull). Remember that interfaces are given to the client that will use them to call these methods.

When you go implementing your interface you won't build a single. long, incomprehensible class but rather you will have different pojos or libraries that does the job for you.

In this way you follow a business object ([BusinessObject j2ee patterns](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/BusinessObject.htm)) model: this pattern is very useful and used to separate business data and business logic (EG. Use pojo for logic and Entity in Dao for business data holder).

As last part, you can use the abstract class in your business. There is always fights against composition and inheritance, you should use abstract class when you don't want anyone to instantiate that type of class. It is a design choise to use "is a" rather then "has a"..

Comment: please take care as much as possible when implements core J2EE patterns. Were usefull 10 years ago, but already many of them are actually deprecated. A common (and modern good practice) pattern for your purpose could be service façade . Please refer to this: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/servicefacade_in_greater_detail_and

Answer (score 0):

A common misleading in OOP is try to use as much inheritance as possible through Abstract Classes, with the pass of the time you could end with long hierarchies and inflexible implementations. Maybe you want some behaviour from 2 different services. What can do you do if multiple inheritance doesnt exist?. OK, you could do some tricks but will be unmaintainable as the software evolves.

EJB are designed under the premise of business interfaces, where the interface is exposed to the clients.  If you need some some behaviour from 2 different services only use the implements keyword as much as you need (dont abuse, you no need a God like service).

Protected methods are tricky and are not usefull to accomplish the EJB intention. So, ok you really need a hierarchy, you could create a **inheritance of interfaces** where some interfaces extends others and some EJB implements that interfaces. This will be more standard and easy to extend.

EDIT: Maybe you were thinking that abstract classes could be a good idea because is possible to have state. In the high performance EJB (as stateless) you should not be using the state because the EJBs are pooled and the correct state is not guaranteed.

Comment: indeed as being stateless the knowledge of state should be something that does not exist..